# WPF checkbox IsChecked binding, OnpropertyChanged not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, checkbox, data-binding

I have a `checkbox` in my view and the binding on it is working fine if i do any modification to my object and trigger the `propertyChanged` event.

On the other side when i click my `checkbox` i perform some logic if the property where it is bound to can be changed. If not i change it back to False and trigger the `propertyChanged` event.

My view is not updating this state of the checbox and it is still checked.

Is this a know problem with any bypass?

Code:

```
<ctrls:CheckBox 
   IsChecked="{Binding IsConverted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

When i change the value and raise the property change event the property is retrieved with the false value:

```
Private _isConverted As Boolean
Public Property IsConverted As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isConverted
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _isConverted = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Where is the code for the logic that you perform, and your invocation of the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: @Jeroen where exactly do you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged?!! I dont really understand where do you get the nerve to vote someone elese answer down on your own question!!! if you already know the answer why are you asking then?

Comment: My setter is a lot more extended then in my example code. It triggers the conversion of the object and in some other methods when the converion is done i trigger the property changed. The view catches this because i'm breaking on the getter of that property and it is returning false. It is then just not updated in the view

Comment: Based on your comments here and to the single answer given so far, there is too much left out for this to be a [mcve]. We *must* have enough context to know what you have done. You claim that you have implemented `INotifiyPropertyChanged` correctly, but your example excludes this. You also claim to be doing a lot of conversion work in the property setter. We can verify neither of these things, or tell you if these are the cause of the issue. We need to see that code to know where the issue lies.

Answer (score -1):

In your Binding in `Xaml`, make sure that `Mode` is set to `TwoWay` so the updates work in both directions.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ViewModelIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Also, now that you posted code, you seem to do things "manually", that should be implemented using the interface INotifyPropertyChanged. Can you drop the UpdateSourceTrigger and just implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel?

There is a good guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Edit:
And because the Poster isn't willing or able to read and understand the guide, here comes the code that is posted there:

```
Public Property PhoneNumber() As String 
    Get 
        Return Me.phoneNumberValue
    End Get 

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Not (value = phoneNumberValue) Then 
            Me.phoneNumberValue = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()          <===== THIS LINE IS DIFFERENT! YOU DON'T HAVE IT. YOU NEED IT.
        End If 
    End Set 
End Property
```

Comment: This interface is implemented, as i mention raise the propertychanged event

Comment: You don't implement it the way Microsoft wants it implemented. If you do it your way, that's great. But don't expect me to help you with your own homebrewn problems when you vote me down trying to tell you how to do it correctly.

Comment: The interface is implemented

Comment: never mind, i'm triggering the property changed correctly, but not from the setter. i'm just trying to explain the issue with the checkbox updating..   The property is triggered i'm getting breaked in the getter, and it is returning False, just the checked property is not changing. All the code to achive this is separated in 5 different object nd is implementing drag and drop logic. unable to show this all... Simple propertychanged implemantation is not the issue at all...

Comment: Even without the 'UpdateSourceTrigger' this problem still exists.., when i can find some spare time i'll try to create a code sample showing the issue. Worked around it right now by removing and adding my item from the observable collection so it gets rerenderen as a whole